# Atualizar as informações da página sem refreesh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Já procurei e não achei exatamente o que eu quero.

O meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho uma página de comentários que eu queria que ela fosse atualizada a cada alteração no banco(isso para todos que estão conectados naquele momento).

Achei alguns métodos na WEB que utilizava `setTimeOut()` para ficar atualizando, mas não gostei muito do resultado....

O meu AJAX para listar está assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabela').empty(); 
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'system/getMessages.php',
            success: function(dados){
                for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                    $('#tabela').append('<tr><td><span>'+dados[i].username+'</span><br />'+dados[i].mensagem+'</td></tr>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

antes este mesmo código estava em um uma função que estava utilizando o método que citei anteriormente(com atualizações JavaScript)

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar WebSocket no HTML 5.

**Apresentando WebSocket**

A especificação WebSocket define uma API que estabelece conexões de "soquete" entre um navegador da web e um servidor. Em outras palavras, há uma conexão persistente entre o cliente e o servidor e ambas as partes podem começar a enviar dados a qualquer momento.

[Aqui](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/) tem o texto completo sobre WebSocket, vale a pena ler tudo, tem como usar também.